# How to select records where time difference is less than X minutes?

Tags: mysql

I need to find all records in table where time difference is less than X minutes? 
Looks like I need:
- to sort table by time (unix time), 
- find current record and previous record in table,
- check difference in current time and previous time,
- and take records if time is less than X minutes

But how will this Mysql request be written?

My Table:

`id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `uniqueid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `publisher` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `booktitle` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `level` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `readinglevel` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `words` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `persent` float(7,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `time` bigint(10) DEFAULT '0',

Comment: Can you show us your table structure? The data type of the column containing the time data will effect the answer. Show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: I've added table structure.

Answer (score 3):

-first off all your time column should be a timestamp type (4B) instead of bigint (8B)

-let's assume time column its a timestamp and the X=1 then you can try something like this:

```
SELECT
    first.id,
    second.id
FROM
    my_table as first
INNER JOIN my_table as second
    ON second.time >= first.time
    ON second.time <= DATE_ADD(first.time, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
WHERE 1
```

But i warn you its extremely inefficient especially if you don't have a index on time column.